# Loop jQuery with PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to use Backstretch to show photos. The plugin requires this code to correspond with a button to display the photo.

```
$("#someId").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.backstretch('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/outside.jpg');
});
```

I have a dynamic site built with PHP, I can loop through my photos to create the thumbnails and links, but I cant get the values into this code. This jQuery code needs to be looped through with the data from the photo PHP loop.
I tried using a .each() loop to grab the data, but still no luck.

Here is what I have so far

```
$(".id").each(function(){
    var id;
    var photo;

   $(this).attr('id', function(i, val){
       id = '#' + val;
       $(".img").each(function(){
           $(this).attr('src', function(i, val){
               photo = val;
            });
       });
console.log(id)
console.log(photo)
        $(id).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.backstretch(photo);
        });
    });
});
```

Nothing seems, to work, any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
<?php 
$category = "urban"; 
$photos = Photo::find_all_category($category);
?>

<script src="js/plugins/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/jquery.backstretch.js"></script>

<div class="row urban">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="row">
<?php foreach($photos as $photo): ?>
        <a class="id" id="<?php echo $photo->id; ?>" src="admin/images/<?php echo $photo->filename; ?>"><img class="img-responsive" src="admin/images/<?php echo $photo->filename; ?>" alt=""></a>

<?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div class="backstretch"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please bring your html code. It seems that you are using nested **each** incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the format to

```
$(".id").each(function(){
var id;
var photo;
id = '#' + (this).getAttribute('id');
console.log(id);
photo = (this).getAttribute('src');
console.log(photo);
$(id).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".backstretch").backstretch(photo);
   });
});
```

And also found I was including jQuery twice. Removed it and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply target the classname:

```
$('.id').click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $(".backstretch").backstretch($(this).attr('src'));
});
```